# Использование Java7 в Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java

При создании проекта я указываю `java-7-openjdk` в поле JRE. Ничего больше  не делая, создаю класс, вызывающий добавленный в Java7 `Object.equals(Object o1, Object o2)`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean b = Object.equals(new World(), new World());
    }
}
```

На что получаю

> equals cannot be resolved or is not a field

Что я упустил?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прошу прощения. Спутал классы `Object` и `Objects`.

Answer (score 0):

переопределить метод сравнения в объекте
т.е. в своем методе Ворд() ты должен переопределить иквелз